# how to populate array of controls (labels) using database vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net

I am doing my homework but stuck on a part. Problem is, How can i populate seat number in array of controls(labels) using database. I already created labels and a class to retrieve all rows from database but how can i apply it in main form and populate labels.

--------------------------Class---------------------------------------

```
  Public Shared Function getOneRow(PK As Integer) As datMovieTimes
            Dim returnRow As New datMovieTimes(0)
            Dim connDB As New SqlConnection
            connDB.ConnectionString = Conn.getConnectionString

            Dim command As New SqlCommand
            command.Connection = connDB
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            command.CommandText = SQLStatements.SELECT_1_BY_ID
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Key", PK)
            Try
                connDB.Open()
                Dim dR As IDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
                If dR.Read() Then
                    returnRow.showingID = PK
                    If Not IsDBNull(dR(Fields.movieID)) Then returnRow.movieID = dR(Fields.movieID)
                    If Not IsDBNull(dR(Fields.dateTime)) Then returnRow.dateTime = dR(Fields.dateTime)
                    If Not IsDBNull(dR(Fields.isActive)) Then returnRow.isActive = dR(Fields.isActive)
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(Err.Description)
            End Try
            Return returnRow
        End Function
        Public Shared Function getAllRows() As Generic.List(Of datMovieTimes)
            Dim returnRows As New Generic.List(Of datMovieTimes)
            Dim connDB As New SqlConnection
            connDB.ConnectionString = Conn.getConnectionString

            Dim command As New SqlCommand
            command.Connection = connDB
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            command.CommandText = SQLStatements.SELECT_ALL
            Try
                connDB.Open()
                Dim dR As IDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
                Do While dR.Read()
                    Dim Row As New datMovieTimes(0)
                    If Not IsDBNull(dR(Fields.showingID)) Then Row.showingID = dR(Fields.showingID)
                    If Not IsDBNull(dR(Fields.movieID)) Then Row.movieID = dR(Fields.movieID)
                    If Not IsDBNull(dR(Fields.dateTime)) Then Row.dateTime = dR(Fields.dateTime)
                    If Not IsDBNull(dR(Fields.isActive)) Then Row.isActive = dR(Fields.isActive)
                    returnRows.Add(Row)
                Loop
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(Err.Description)
            End Try
            Return returnRows
        End Function
```

-----------------------------main form-----------------------------------------

```
    Public Sub createSeat()

    Dim S1 As Label

    For X As Integer = 1 To _MAX_X
        For Y As Integer = 1 To _MAX_Y
            S1 = New Label

            S1.Height = 25
            S1.Width = 25
            S1.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            S1.Top = 100 + (X - 1) * (S1.Height + 5)
            S1.Left = 200 + (Y - 1) * (S1.Width + 5)
            S1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            S1.Text = Y.ToString

            AddHandler S1.Click, AddressOf GenericLabel_Click
            Me.Controls.Add(S1)
            _SeatArray(X, Y) = S1

        Next
    Next


    For X As Integer = 0 To 9
        _AlphaLabel(X) = New Label
        _AlphaLabel(X).Height = 25
        _AlphaLabel(X).Width = 25
        _AlphaLabel(X).BackColor = Color.Transparent
        _AlphaLabel(X).Top = 130 + (X - 1) * (_AlphaLabel(X).Height + 6)
        _AlphaLabel(X).Left = 170
        _AlphaLabel(X).Text = _AlphaName(X)
        Me.Controls.Add(_AlphaLabel(X))
    Next
End Sub


Private Sub GenericLabel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim L As New Label
    L = DirectCast(sender, Label)

    If L.BackColor = Color.LightGreen Then
        L.BackColor = Color.Orange
        clickLess -= 1
    ElseIf L.BackColor = Color.Orange Then
        L.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        clickLess += 1
    End If

    clickCount += 1
    Me.lblRemainingCount.Text = clickLess.ToString
    Me.nudTicketsCount.Value = clickCount

    If clickLess <= 0 Then
        MsgBox("No more seats left.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "House Full")
    End If

End Sub
```

[Database pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXVYa.png)

Comment: You can set each label's "Name" property when you are creating/adding them to the form, in your case you would probably use a row number or seat location like "A2" or something. Then you can search for the labels by name later

Comment: is it like label1, label2, label3 something after handle.

Answer (score 0):

When creating labels, insert one more line:

```
S1.Name = "MyLabel" & X & Y
```

When accessing the label:

```
Dim MyCurrentLabel as Label
MyCurrentLabel = CType("MyLabel" & X & Y, Label)
```

Then you can do things with the current label:

```
MyCurrentLabel.Text = "Hello World"
```

Comment: i added counter and numbered it

Comment: You should accept it as an answer or write down your solution as an answer, so that future visitors having the same problem see the solution...

Answer (score 0):

[current image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG1cc.png)

Now it is something like this, so it want to change the colour to red if it is paid according to database.
Thanks

Comment: Ah, I see. I'd do that with a bitmap and graphics FillRectangle and DrawString, it would be easier and much faster... You will get most probably a little lag when starting the form. But your way will do the job too...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, sorry i forgot to mention it because i was busy in completing the project

----------------------Seat creation----------------------------------------

```
   Public Sub createSeat()

    Dim S1 As Label
    Dim numValue As Integer = 1

    For X As Integer = 1 To _MAX_X
        For Y As Integer = 1 To _MAX_Y
            S1 = New Label

            S1.Height = 25
            S1.Width = 25
            S1.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            S1.Top = 180 + (X - 1) * (S1.Height + 5)
            S1.Left = 200 + (Y - 1) * (S1.Width + 5)
            S1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            S1.Text = Y.ToString
            ' S1.Text = numValue
            S1.Name = "Label" & numValue
            AddHandler S1.Click, AddressOf GenericLabel_Click
            Me.Controls.Add(S1)
            _SeatArray(X, Y) = S1
            numValue += 1
        Next
    Next


    For X As Integer = 0 To 9
        _AlphaLabel(X) = New Label
        _AlphaLabel(X).Height = 25
        _AlphaLabel(X).Width = 25
        _AlphaLabel(X).BackColor = Color.Transparent
        _AlphaLabel(X).Top = 210 + (X - 1) * (_AlphaLabel(X).Height + 6)
        _AlphaLabel(X).Left = 170
        _AlphaLabel(X).Text = _AlphaName(X)
        Me.Controls.Add(_AlphaLabel(X))
    Next
End Sub
```

-------------------------------populate seat number----------------------------------

```
 Public Sub populateSeatNumber()

    Dim connectionString As String = DBL.Conn.getConnectionString

    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    connection.Open()
    Dim selectStatement As String = "SELECT * FROM datTicketsSold"

    Dim selectCommand As New SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection)

    Dim daSoldTickets As New SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand)
    Dim dsSoldTickets As DataSet = New DataSet

    daSoldTickets.Fill(dsSoldTickets, "datTicketsSold")
    connection.Close()

    Dim dtTickets As DataTable = dsSoldTickets.Tables("datTicketsSold")

    Dim row As DataRow

    For Each row In dtTickets.Rows
        If row(3) = True Then
            CType(Controls("Label" & row(2)), Label).BackColor = Color.Red
            redCounter += 1
        Else
            CType(Controls("Label" & row(2)), Label).BackColor = Color.Yellow
            yellowCounter += 1
        End If
    Next
    Me.lblReservedCount.Text = yellowCounter.ToString
    Me.lblSoldCount.Text = redCounter.ToString
End Sub
```

Thanks everyone